# Need Javascript mathematical expression or formula to place number range in groups

Tags: javascript, mathematical-optimization

Need some quick help determining an equation or formula for taking a given number with min/max range, and evaluating it into 1 of 3 'groups.' Being a bit lazy I know, but wanted to see if there was a clever equation I could use rather than a switch/case statement.

Input:

```
0–5
```

Output (groups/returned integers):

```
0, 1, or 2
```

Mapping (input must fall into/equal output):

```
0–2 = 0
3 = 1
4–5 = 2
```

Comment: You mean something like `Math.floor((val - min) / (max - min) * numofgroups)`?

Comment: Or rather a simple `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2][val]` for this specific case?

Comment: Try: `2*(x>3)+(x==3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to do better performance-wise than the switch/case.   But if you want extra-clever, howsabout:

```
(x >> 2) + (x >= 3)
```

Comment: This solution and @tewathia's comment both gave me exactly what I wanted. Adding Booleans - awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function InRangeOrNot(value)
 {
  var result;

  switch (true)
  {
   case (value == 0):
    result = "Equals Zero.";
    break;
   
   case ((value >= 1) && (value <= 500)):
    result = "In Between 1 and 500.";
    break;


   default:
    result = "Not found in the range.";
    break;
  }
alert(result);
  return result;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
First name: 
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: 
<input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="InRangeOrNot(10)">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```